# input hidden value doesn't send to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying post to my database,everything what i want i can get from my formcollection and my table but input hidden value.My main view is using @model List

Here is my code this my modal popup

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("update3", "UpdateInfo", FormMethod.Post))
{

<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="mymodal">



    <form id="stok_formu">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">


                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>



                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="modal2">

                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="names" id="name" name="name"></label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="names" name="names" />
                        
                   
                    </div><br />

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            @Html.Label(" Clothes codes: ")
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">

                            <input type="number" class="input-sm" id="codes" name="codes" />
                        </div>
                    </div><br />

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            @Html.Label("New Price : ")
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">

                            <input type="number" class="input-sm" id="newprice" name="newprice" />
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <input class="btn btn-success" id="change"  type = "submit" name="change"/>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
</div>
}
```

With this javascript code ,i can get my "name" from my table and put on my modal and my problem is begin is here,when i click button submit modal popup doesn't send hidden value to controller but ican get my  value of "newprice"

```
 function metot(x) {
        namee = document.getElementById("tablo2").rows[0].cells.item(0).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = namee;
    }
```

and table from my main view

```
 <tbody id="tablo2">


        @foreach(var oge in Model)
        {
            <tr onclick="metot(this)">
                <td>@Html.Encode(oge.name)</td>
                <td id="codes">@Html.Encode(oge.codes)</td>
                <td id="price">@Html.Encode(oge.price)</td>
                <td>
                    <button  id="change" onclick="metot(this)"  type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal" class="btn btn-warning tab-content"><span>Change</span></button>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the text of the label with id `name`, but you aren't setting the value of the hidden field with id `names`, hence it is not sent when you submit the form. `<label>` elements do not send data back to the server.

This should work (I assume the variable `namee` should actually be called `urun_adi`):

```
function metot(x) {
    urun_adi = document.getElementById("tablo2").rows[0].cells.item(0).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = urun_adi;
    document.getElementById("names").value = urun_adi;
}
```

Comment: still data doesn't return  just this => ""

Comment: Which value in the formcollection is empty? `name` or `names` (or both)?

Comment: Done ! thank you ,your first solution was correct ,i wrote wrong in code  sorry :)